# Can't connect to WebSocket inside Service Worker

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket, service-worker

Can't connect to WebSocket inside Service Worker!

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://46.101.***.***");
```

Response

> (Opcode -1)

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [this GitHub issue on the W3C service worker repo](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/947), service workers do not support WebSocket.

Comment: Apparently it's working on Chrome 68.0.3440.84 (64 bit). Tested in Ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: Seems the issue was closed because it is supported now? I haven't checked all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a web-socket connection inside a service worker. Or you can use `web-workers` here to maintain the websocket.

Comment: I don't understand why it's can't create websocket connection inside service-worker